# display table-cell no funciona bien en safari

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de diseñar un componente con un input y un boton justo alado, es para hacer una busqueda, dentro del css estoy usando display table, para alinear los componentes.

El problema es que en chrome funciona bien el heigth que le aplico al boton para que utilice el 100% de su contenedor padre (en este caso span), alguien podria ayudarme?.

Estoy buscando la solucion por que deja esos cuantos pixeles de diferencia y no se alinea a la par con el input text

acontinuacion les dejo un [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/lpnwisdom/pen/VPVNgj) en donde estoy realizando el codigo:

Asi es como se ve en firefox: 
[![Asi es como se ve en firefox: ][2]][2]

Asi se ve en safari:

[image: Asi se ve en safari:]

Comment: Hola, utilize `display:flex;` en div.wrapper-input

Comment: Si bien es válido hacer referencia a recursos externos, la preguntas debe incluir toda la información relevante. Cabe mencionar que Stack Overflow en español tiene la herramienta framento HTML/JavaScript/CSS por lo que no usualmente no es necesario recurrir a herramientas externas similares.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo una solución con bootstrap espero te sirva.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/custom-search-input

Comment: En este sitio no se permiten las respuetas que sólo incluyen un enlace. Esta respuesta es prácticamente eso. Si bien es válido incluir referencias a recursos externos, la respuesta debería incluir un breve descripción y las partes más relevantes.